# Express bodyParser creates array on duplicate parameter in URL

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I have Express using bodyParser. If the request has a duplicate key in it, for example

```
http://a.b.com?id=1&id=1&name=boo
```

The data I get is

```
{
    id: [ "1", "1" ],
    name: "boo"
}
```

How can I have all parameters treated as strings and give me a sparse object?

What I need is

```
{
    id: "1",
    name: "boo"
}
```

I know, what if the values are different for same key.

```
http://a.b.com?id=1&id=2&name=boo
```

I can still live with just the first value

```
{
    id: "1",
    name: "boo"
}
```

I can handle this after I get req.body. I was wondering if there is any options we can use to do this in bodyParser. I tried `extended: false`, no  luck.

Comment: Try this: `req.body.id[0]`

Answer (score 2):

That's actually in line with the spec.

Check https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html for example.

If you have a lot of properties like that, you could map them to the first element of the array, provided that's what you always want.